# Error while executing oracle procedure using liquibase

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, liquibase

I am trying to run the following using liquibase

```sql
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset id:1
DECLARE str varchar(30);
BEGIN
    str := 'something';
    update table_name set comment = str where id=1; 
END;
```

But I am getting the following error. How to fix this?

```
[ERROR]      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 23:
[ERROR] PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]    := ; not null default character
[ERROR]  [Failed SQL: DECLARE str varchar(30)]
```

If I remove ';' after DECLARE and execute I am getting the following error

```
[ERROR] PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]    := ; not null default character
[ERROR] The symbol ";" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.
[ERROR] ORA-06550: line 3, column 16:
[ERROR] PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]    * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
[ERROR]    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
[ERROR]    like4 likec between || multiset m
[ERROR]  [Failed SQL: DECLARE str varchar(30)
[ERROR] BEGIN
[ERROR]     str := 'something']
```

EDIT:

From help in comments my issue got fixed by adding "/" at the end

```sql
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset id:1
DECLARE str varchar(30);
BEGIN
    str := 'something';
    update table_name set comment = str where id=1; 
END;
/
```

Comment: Can you try omitting the ; in the line with DECLARE?

Comment: I guess you only need a `/` at the end.

Comment: For start I think you need to put the table name in your update statement and not "table" word: demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3e644065122029c8e99de832604ef73b

Comment: @VBokšić I am putting actual name in query just for reference I mentioned it like this.

Comment: Then the answer from @AnkitBajpai looks correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d5309c0eb05e9424358df21ca2a744a6

Comment: @VBokšić, Because I had banged my head for hours just for this.

Comment: Thank you. I have been banging my head for past five hours and it just got fixed with small /.